# Suggestion needed for developing enormous web application

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mongodb, database

I have been given the contract of making a big web application for a private bus transport company. Before I elaborate the question, here's a few things:

It is a complete web based and application that will be used to:

- Manage Vehicles, Routes, Bus Stoppages
- Current location using GPS and calculations.
- Print tickets
- Online Purchase
- Membership
- Full accounts management (i.e. income, expenses, graphical reports etc)
- A website working simultaneously allowing to book/cancel tickets, and live chat.

All that said, my question is that what would be the appropriate environment and tools to build the app?

1. Programming Lingo: (My choice, MVC based JavaScript framework with PHP in the back to provide data and views) Give me your suggestions.
2. DataBase: This is where I am mostly confused. Should I use mysql? or something OOP like mongoDB?
3. Other tools: What other tools may aid me? suggest please.

And, I have to do this alone. Hiring people/outsourcing/teaming is not an option.

Comment: If you have to ask, you aren't up to it.  Better go out and hire some help right away or you'll run the risk of violating that contract.

Comment: I have several cheeses to choose from, which do I pick? Depends on your budget, coding skill, server, timespan and a million other things

Comment: I suggest you take a look at existing e-commerce frameworks instead, and modify/plug-in missing functionality them to suit your needs. Scratch-coding this project will NOT be easy.

Comment: Well, thanks for answering. I looked into the existing frameworks such as Magneto and others. But they are just too focused on "selling" and marketing. Adding additional features is going to be really painful, and all that, after passing the learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep everything as simple as possible if you wish to have any chance of delivering on time.

Use MySQL or something similar if you have used it before, because such a large project is probably not a good place to learn new things especially if time is critical.

If you have used an MVC framework before, use it again, because you don't want to spend days learning a new one for such a large project unless you are sure there are tangible benefits.

Once you choose a framework you can look for tools to assist you. For example, if you chose the java framework tapestry, you could use the eclipse IDE to help you program productively.

Good luck.

Comment: And yeah, if you are able to extend Magneto or something which already provides half of the functionality, I would do that. Your project looks to be a massive undertaking for one man if you have time constraints.

Comment: That's an ENOURMOUS project. You really need to use as much off the shelf as possible. Only code the things that are unique to the project. I don't expect you'll have time to develop solutions to solved problems.

Comment: Especially details like "live chat" and graphical reports...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This doesn't particularly help me with a tool but points me to what I should do next, in general.

Grateful for that.

Comment: @SayemShafayet No problem. Don't underestimate the size of the project and the number of tasks involved, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Programming** - If you want PHP based MVC, I suggest go for CodeIgniter. Its simple to learn.  I have used it earlier and found it quite good.

**Database**: If there is no specific need to go for NOSQL based database, use MySQL.

Start by creating a data model, then create APIs to read write them. Integrate all these in a website.

All this is going to be a very big work if one person has to do it alone. One options could be to explore tools and frameworks for various components and integrate them in your site. e.g. openfire for chat, open source web based software for accounting and reporting.